# Visual studio building error on other computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, build

Once in a while I need to test an application on another computer then the one it is been being developed on. Today when I came to visit a company, I develop the software for, I run into an issue. When I tried to build the solution on their computer the otherwise flawless building process threw an error.

To be concrete:

```
The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)
   at System.Drawing.Image.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.WriteValue(ResourceTypeCode typeCode, Object value, BinaryWriter writer, IFormatter objFormatter)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Generate()
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, IResourceWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteBinaryResources(ReaderInfo reader, String filename)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, String filename)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFileOrDir)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 satelliteInputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, Boolean usePreserializedResources, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() SpektrometrMain
```

Sometimes it suffices to give it a few more tries and the build succeeds. However, the other time it completely breaks the solution, when Windows.Forms designer class announces unreasonable errors such as that some variables missing declarition (while quite obviosly they don't).I am pretty confused about that, since on my computer all projects within the solution build flawlessly. After conducting a short research on google I came across a few advices of which none have helped.

**What I have tried:**

Cleaning the solution and rebuilding it.

Deleting bin and obj folders and rebuilding the solution.

Removing git source control (also worthy meantioning that this issue ocured shortly after implementing git on companies computer)

Has anyone encountred such a problem or wouln't you have any tips what to look for?

Comment: Is this build being done in VS? If so, I'd suggest trying a repair.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It is. What do you mean by "repair"?

Comment: Repair is an option in the VS installer. It's basically a reinstall without uninstalling. It will fix any corrupt or missing files.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have just finished the repair, but unfortunatelly it hasn't had a desired impact.

Comment: A little bit aside, but why are you building on the client computer(s) at all?  Why not do a publish/deployment from your machine?  Is there some specific environmental reason to build on the companies computers?

Comment: @Hursey Originally I wasn't hired as a programmer, but after a while I found myself loving it and enjoying it so they assigned me a few projects. However, I guess they want to approach my programs with caution, since they could easily cause mess in their system or damage the spectrometer. I stand behind my work, but I understand their point of view.

Comment: Take as took at: [https://codeserendipity.com/2017/01/23/error-the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly/](https://codeserendipity.com/2017/01/23/error-the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly/).

Comment: @AnoopRana certainly! Thank you for looking into that. I deleted it, becuase I realized I made a silly mistake. I still had to invoke a small workaroud though, so your explanation will still be greatly apprecaited :). I undeleted the question, please share your solution.

Comment: @PepaZdepa Yes, i have posted the solution. There are 2 ways to solve it. If you need any clarification about that answer, feel free to post a comment below my answer there. Note that i have used an empty `Board` class there so that the answer doesn't get too long because the `Board` class you provided is very big(in length) and so would take a lot of space when posting 2 times in my answer. But the concept is the same.